# Javascript, simple extension method that allows multiple versions of extending object

Tags: javascript, extend

I have a straightforward "extend" method set up like this:

```
extend: function(source) {
    for (var k in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            myThing[k] = source[k];
        }
    }
    return myThing;
}
```

You use it like

```
myThing.extend({ 
    newObj: { 
        myFunc: function () { console.log('things'); }
    }
});
```

and it works great.
However, I would love to add the ability to have some other piece of code call this LATER:

```
myThing.extend({ 
        newObj: { 
            mySecondFunc: function () { console.log('things'); }
        }
    });
```

and I should be able to call both `myThing.newObj.myFunc()` AND `myThing.newObj.mySecondFunc()`.

I tried changing it to this:

```
for (var k in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                if (mtUtils.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    for (var t in k) {
                        mtUtils[k][t] = source[k][t];
                    }
                } else {
                    mtUtils[k] = source[k];
                }
            }
        }
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I recommend looking at the different patterns that Douglas Crockford has implemented. http://javascript.crockford.com/

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals : Which part?  You just sent me to the entire website.

Comment: I suggest http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals : I wasn't looking for object inheritance though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem, but why not implement a recursive version of `extend`?

```
    for (var k in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            if (mtUtils.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                for (var t in source[k]) {
                    mtUtils[k][t] = source[k][t];
                }
            } else {
                mtUtils[k] = source[k];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I posted that I tried but it didn't work?  It SHOULD have worked, but didn't so maybe I just needed to clear cache or something.  Either way, I have implemented a recursive version just like you suggest.

Comment: @JamesP.Wright I believe you misspelled `for (var t in source[k]) {` in your code, which I corrected. So it's not *exactly* what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
function extend(dest, source) {
    for (var k in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            var value = source[k];
            if (dest.hasOwnProperty(k) && typeof dest[k] === "object" && typeof value === "object") {
                extend(dest[k], value);
            } else {
                dest[k] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
var myThing = {};
extend(myThing, {
    newObj: {
        myFunc: function() {
            console.log('things');
        }
    }
});
extend(myThing, {
    newObj: {
        mySecondFunc: function() {
            console.log('things');
        }
    }
});

myThing;
/*
Object
   newObj: Object
      myFunc: function () { console.log('things'); }
      mySecondFunc: function () { console.log('things'); }
      __proto__: Object
   __proto__: Object
*/
```